# Problems with unique permissions in a list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, permissions, access-denied

I have a list that has unique permissions. I have a user who has permission collaboration in this list, the rest of the site he has no permission.

When the user accesses the link list, he gets the access denied error.

I thought that the error might be because he does not have access to the site logo. Gave permission to display the logo, but not helped.

I have SharePoint 2013.

Update

Exclusive List Permissions:
[image: Exclusive List Permissions]

Site permissions:
[image: Site permissions]

As described in the site the user is not allowed, only the list.

The language of my SharePoint is in Portuguese

Comment: Go to list settings>permissions > check permissions : enter the domain username of the effected user and check his permissions on the list. Share the details preferably in a screenshot. This will help us understand the situation better

Comment: Ok I go do this

Comment: I've got the same problem here.
Give unique permission on a document library at a SubSite and no 'limited access' in the Sub-Site permissions. That is really annoying.... :(

Comment: The worst is that I have it in my farm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add permissions for a user to a list only (let’s say contribute rights) SharePoint will add contribute permissions to the list and also will automatically add Limited Access for that user on the site that contains the list so the user can navigate to the list. If you delete that ‘Limited Access’ permission for that user on site level then that should delete his list permissions too, automatically.

Interesting in your case is how it ended up having no Limited Access site permission but still ‘having’ Contribute permissions on the list.

Try giving permissions for that user to the list again and check is the user granted ‘Limited Access’  permission on site level.

Comment: Tanks, I try this.

Comment: Deletes the user's permission on the list. Added permission again and then checked that the user had permission on the site continued to be none.

Comment: I agree with you, it's interesting to have permission on the list and no website.

Comment: That’s weird. I have no clue why SharePoint is not doing it automatically. What kind of list it is anyway? document library, pages library, standard list?

Comment: Is a standard list (Custom List)

Comment: Try with another test list in the same site or another test site. Break role inheritance and give this user contribute rights and then check is the user granted Limited Access on site level. At least you will know is the problem with your list or it's happening for every list and site. If its happening everywhere test with another web application too.

Comment: Ok, I try this.

Comment: It happens in all web applications

Comment: I'm guessing some link that the user has no access is disturbing user access the page.

Comment: Maybe but it's weird why it's not adding Limited Access on the web.

Comment: Tested on another website that is in another web application, same problem.

Comment: Then it seems it's a farm level problem and needs more investigation. Any other problem in the farm? Start by looking in event logs and uls logs just after you grant permissions for a user in a list. Also check service applications, diagnostics, sql servers etc. It's certainly not a normal behaviour for SharePoint.